# is Java pass by reference or pass by value after method references where introduced in the language

Tags: java

I do know that values in Java are passed by value.

resources:

[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

https://www.journaldev.com/3884/java-is-pass-by-value-and-not-pass-by-reference
[...]

Just wanted to know if after introduction of method references (::) Java is still considered as passed by value.

Comment: "Reference" in "method reference" and in "pass by reference" does not hold the same meaning. It's all pass by value whether the invocation of a method follows a method reference or not.

Comment: References in Java are also passed by value. A method reference is just another type of reference. It doesn't change how anything is passed in Java (by value)

Comment: A method reference isn’t passed by anything. It’s syntactic sugar for a lambda (ish) and desugars to a `static` method invoked by `invokedynamic` (ish).